# Why does Angular update modifies template files?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Almost all the template files, the migration step has added some attributes to templates automatically.
So, what should I do now, now my application has both in different files. Should I maintain consistency to only have any of the two variants in entire application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the source code of [`mat-form-field`(v15)](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/15.0.0/src/material/form-field/form-field.ts#L56) line 56.

```
/** Possible appearance styles for the form field. */
export type MatFormFieldAppearance = 'fill' | 'outline';
```

When looking at [`mat-formfield`(v14)](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/14.0.0/src/material/form-field/form-field.ts) These are the valid types!

```
/** Possible appearance styles for the form field. */
export type MatFormFieldAppearance = 'legacy' | 'standard' | 'fill' | 'outline';
```

---

So to conclude `outlined` is either a `typo or incorrect value`, go with `'outline'` throughout the usages!